# eregi replaced with preg_match brings error back

Tags: php, preg-match

I am quite new to php so excuse my poor knowledge but I am using an email form for users to register on my web page but I am getting errors running it.

the full script is as follow:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "contact@slapmybeat.com";
    $email_subject = "New e-mail subscriber";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form your submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if
        (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the email your submitted.');     
    }


    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/";
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }


    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?
}
?>
```

First I had a "eregi depreciated" error because of the initial script which was as follow:

```
        $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
  if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
```

After googling it I replaced it with:

```
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/";
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
```

but now it is giving me the following, although the email adress is correct:

> We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form your
>   submitted. These errors appear below.
>
> The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
>
> Please go back and fix these errors.

any help will be much apreciated

Comment: Word of advice: Find more than 1 (email) form on the Web and test them. One is bound to work without failure. There are literally thousands out there, many with already built-in security features and validation. Don't limit yourself to just the one. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eregi` is case-insensitive, `preg_match` is not.

You have to add `i` to the end of the pattern (`/..../i`).

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but if you want to check for a valid e-mail address, it is a lot easier to use php's built-in [filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
$email = filter_var($email_from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Now `$email` will contain the filtered e-mail address or `false` if the filter failed (not a valid address in this case).

Answer (score -1):

You should escape the "." inside the [] because it will match every character if you don't do it, you'll have:

```
"/^[A-Z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i"
```

Comment: Wrong. Only ^, \, -, and ] metacharacters have special meaning within [ ], and need to be escaped (^ only if first, - only if not last).

Comment: @Phil Ok, but isn't my Regex valid regarding your comment ?

Comment: You made the specific statement that "." has to be escaped because it will match everything, and that's not true. "." inside [] has no special meaning (at least in standard regexp implementations). It doesn't _hurt_ to escape it, but it's not required.